Finiteness of the Kac table for minimal model
I am currently reading CFT from Di Francesco. I am stuck at not understanding why the kac table for minimal models $(p, q)$ where $p$ and $q$ are co-prime, only has fields with conformal dimension $h_{r, s}$ s.t. $r \in [0, p-1]$ and $s \in [0, p' - 1]$. I understand the Verma Models highest weight state needs to conformal dimension in this form
$$h_{r,s} = \frac{(pr - qs)^2 - (p-q)^2}{4pq}$$
to have singular vectors and be reducible. But, why is the allowed values of $r$ and $s$ bounded. Any positive integer values of $r$ and $s$ can give you reducible Verma module.

For generic central charge there exists a so-called generalized minimal model, which has fields with dimensions $h_{r,s}$ for any $r,s\in \mathbb{N}^*$.
In a minimal model, the central charge is such that $h_{r,s}=h_{q-r,p-s}$, and each degenerate field is in fact multiply degenerate. This leads to stronger constraints on the fusion rules. Due to these constraints, the Kac table is closed under fusion, which means that primary fields with $r\geq q$ or $s\geq p$ never appear in OPEs of primary fields from the Kac table.
By definition, in a minimal model we have only finitely many primary fields. Using degenerate representations, i.e. irreducible quotients of reducible Verma modules, is necessary but not sufficient for that.
For more details along these lines see https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.09523 .
